# dockerfile COPY does not copy all the files

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I do

- `git clone https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin.git`
- cd `zipkin`

The create a Dockerfile as below

```
FROM openjdk

RUN mkdir app

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ .

ENTRYPOINT ["sleep", "1000000"]
```

then

- `docker build -t abc .`
- `docker run abc`

I then run `docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash`

`pwd` returns `/app` which is expected

**but I `ls` and see that the files are not copied**

only the directories and the xml file is copied into the `/app` directory

[image]

What is the reason? how to fix it?

Also I tried

```
FROM openjdk

RUN mkdir app

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT ["sleep", "1000000"]
```

Comment: zipkin folder don't contains the files showed in your image. It contains the root files. Share where and how are you executing the docker build...

Comment: Include the contents of the `.dockerignore`. Also, what's in the picture? I can't make it out on my phone. Post formatted text instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That repository contains a [`.dockerignore`](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/blob/master/.dockerignore) file which excludes everything except a set of things it selects.

That repository's [`docker`](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/tree/master/docker) directory also contains several build scripts for [official images](https://hub.docker.com/r/openzipkin/zipkin) and you may find it easier to start your custom image `FROM openzipkin/zipkin` rather than trying to reinvent it.

Comment: I wish I could. I am in a big organization The aqua scan is not being passed for the zipkin image and I have to create the image from the source code so that I can make some changes such as using our own os image.